# Why setting image path with JS-code it has 0 sizes?

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css

In laravel app with alpinejs 3.4 and tailwindcss ^3.1 I set content of components
with html and javascript code :

```
<div class="info_badge_internal_block">
    <div class="info_badge_image_wrapper">
        <img src="/images/emptyImg.png" id="img_{{ $badgeLabel }}"
            alt="Hidden subscriptions"
            title="Hidden subscriptions" class="info_badge_image">
    </div>
    ...
    


// document.getElementById("img_{{ $badgeLabel }}").style.removeProperty('max-width')
// document.getElementById("img_{{ $badgeLabel }}").style.removeProperty('maxWidth')

document.getElementById("img_{{ $badgeLabel }}").src = details.image + '?d=' + Date.now()
// document.getElementById("img_{{ $badgeLabel }}").classsName = 'info_badge_image'
```

I set image path with JS-code above and image is assigned, but it is not visible and in browser's console I see
it has 0*0 size. I see "img" class assigned, but I my code has no any "img" class. I suppose it it somewhere
from tailwind core...

If to uncheck max-width property of "img" class in browser's console I see my image with valid size.

https://prnt.sc/97_OuC0cKLGS

In the top of my resources/css/app.css file I have lines :

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;


@layer base {
   ...
```

I tried to modify  "img" class in my resources/css/app.css file - but no effects.

Where is  "img" class  from and how that issue can be fixed ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I see "img" class assigned, but I my code has no any "img" class. I suppose it it somewhere from tailwind core...

The screenshot shows the CSS is targeting all `<img />` tags, not elements with the class name of `img`. Adding the class `max-w-auto` to the `<img />` tag should overwrite the `max-with: 100%` which would fix your problem.